# about `condition` must be a logical vector, not a `quosures` object

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create an indicator variable.

```
 data<-data.frame(id=seq(1,10,1),DX1=c(1,0,4,0,0,4,1,0,0,0),DX2=c(1,0,4,0,4,0,0,4,0,0),DX3=c(1,0,5,0,1,5,1,0,5,0))


data$indicator<-ifelse(data$DX1>=3|data$DX2>=3|data$DX3>=3,1,0)
```

How can we use ifelse or dplyr since I hae DX1-DX100 columns.

One solution is

```
data$max<-apply(X = data, MARGIN = 1, FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE)

data<-data%>%mutate(variable=ifelse(max>3,1,0))
```

Can we use dplyr?

```
data<-data%>%mutate(indicator=if_else(vars(contains("DX")),   any_vars(.>=3)) , 1, 0)
```

I got an error message saying that`condition` must be a logical vector, not a `quosures` object

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the ifelse function, you can just use a logical statment along with the rowSums function:

```
data$indicator <- rowSums(data[,-1]) >= 3
```

Or, if it needs to be int instead:

```
data$indicator <- as.integer(rowSums(data[,-1]) >= 3)
```

Or, if the dataframe contains more than just the index and numbered DX columns, and you need to more precisely subset, you can use grepl to get the indices of column names containing the substring 'DX':

```
data$indicator <- as.integer(rowSums(data[grepl('DX', colnames(data))]) >= 3)
```

And obviously, any of these can be used in a dplyr context, like so:

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate(indicator = as.integer(rowSums(data[,-1]) >= 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are few ways to do it

```
cols <- grep("^DX", names(data))
data$indicator <- as.integer(rowSums(data[cols] > 3) > 0)

data
#   id DX1 DX2 DX3 indicator
#1   1   1   1   1         0
#2   2   0   0   0         0
#3   3   4   4   5         1
#4   4   0   0   0         0
#5   5   0   4   1         1
#6   6   4   0   5         1
#7   7   1   0   1         0
#8   8   0   4   0         1
#9   9   0   0   5         1
#10 10   0   0   0         0
```

We can use the same using `dplyr::mutate`

```
data %>% mutate(indicator = as.integer(rowSums(.[cols] > 3) > 0))
```

---

We can also use `apply`

```
data$indicator <- as.integer(apply(data[cols] > 3, 1, any))
```

---

Or using `purrr::pmap_int`

```
data %>%
  mutate(indicator = purrr::pmap_int(select(., contains("DX")), ~any(c(...) > 3)))
```